# How to assign a class and toggle a expandable menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    var vStr = "2.1";
    var vULSize = $("#uSPStyle li:not(li li)").size();
    var vULSubSize;
    if (vStr.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        var vSplit = vStr.split(".");
        var vFirst = vSplit[0];
        var vSecond = vSplit[1];
        console.log(vFirst); //first number
        console.log(vSecond); //second number
        console.log(vULSize); //size of the parent UL
        if (vFirst <= vULSize) { //if the first number is less than or equal to the parent UL size
            //{need help}remove 'current' class from the existing parent LI
            $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").addClass("current"); //{need help}add the 'current' class to the parent LI
            vULSubSize = ""; //{need help}get the size of the sub UL inside the above LI
            if (vSecond <= vULSubSize) { //if the number is less than or equal to the size of the sub UL
                $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").find("ul").slideToggle(); //{need help}expand the sub UL inside the LI
                $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").find("ul li:eq(" + vSecond + ")").addClass("current"); //{need help}add the 'current class to the sub UL LI
                $('.dispArtBody').addClass('hideContent'); //{need help}hide all content
                var element = $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").find("ul li:eq(" + vSecond + ")").attr("data-toggle"); //{need help}get the class of the LI which corresponds to the body class
                $(element).removeClass('hideContent'); //{need help}show that content which corresponds to the element
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //{need help}remove 'current' class from the existing parent LI
        $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").addClass("current"); //{need help}add the 'current' class to the parent LI
        $('.dispArtBody').addClass('hideContent'); //{need help}hide all content
        var element = $("#uSPStyle li:eq(" + vFirst + ")").attr("data-toggle"); //{need help}get the class of the LI which corresponds to the body class
        $(element).removeClass('hideContent'); //{need help}show that content which corresponds to the element
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qweu58f/6/

For example, If `vStr` is `2.1` then "CARE" `LI` should lose the `current` class and "BC" `LI` should get the `current` class. "OUR LINK" `LI` should also get the `current` class and `<div class="tf1SLink2 dispArtBody hideContent"><tf1SText02>This is for second link sublink 1</tf1SText02></div>` should be displayed because it corresponds to the first LI of the sub UL to the second LI of the parent UL.

Please help me complete the script above to accomplish that. The removeClass and addClass is not working at all for me.

I am just trying to replicate the click event also through a page load event. So the `2.1` would be in the URL, for example: `www.mysite1.com/mypage.aspx?id=9090&menuid=2.1`

Answer (score 1):

Only a minor edit:

```
if (vFirst <= vULSize) {
    // remove .current from every top level just to be sure
    $("#uSPStyle li a").removeClass("current");

    // next line accomplishes two goals:
    // adds .current to the a tag inside the correct li (you were adding it to the li)
    // gets the size for vULSubSize (you were setting this to "" for some reason)
    vULSubSize = $("#uSPStyle > li:eq(" + (vFirst-1) + ") a").addClass("current").size();
```

You can see above that I've specified the `li` has to be a direct descendant of `$("#uSPStyle")` when we add `.current`, this is because there are other lower lever children that this should not be applied to. We also now use `(vFirst-1)` - because `:eq()` works on an index basis, `1` in the string equates to the 0th element.

Corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nxpq3d8/2/)

---

For second level (after your edits), you would want to use

```
$("#uSPStyle > li:eq(" + vFirst + ") > ul > li:eq(" + vSecond + ") a").addClass("current");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qweu58f/9/

Comment: How can I assign the `current` class to the sub LI of the UL? `$("#uSPStyle li:not(li li):eq(" + vFirst + ")").find("a").closest("li").children("ul li:eq(" + vSecond + ")").find("a").eq(0).addClass("current");` didn't work for me. BC (current class) and OUR LINK (current class). The script is for OUR LINK.

Comment: see my edit for the first comment. adding `.current` to the subs should follow exactly the same procedure, making careful note of my end paragraph

Comment: That one didn't work unfortunately. This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/5qweu58f/7/ (I am able to select `BC` and then because I have the `0` in vStr, I also would want `OUR LINK` to get the class as well). Thank you.

Comment: See my edit for second level. You do need to decide whether 1 in the string will mean the 1st element or the 2nd element, because it seems to be inconsistant at the moment. That's a design decision for you to take though.

Comment: so far with 0 being the first element is working for me in the fiddle.